# Dividing a 9x9 2d array into 9 sub-grids (like in sudoku)? (C++)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I'm trying to code a sudoku solver, and the way I attempted to do so was to have a 9x9 grid of pointers that hold the address of "set" objects that posses either the solution or valid possible values.

I was able to go through the array with 2 for loops, through each column first and then going to the next row and repeating.

However, I'm having a hard time imagining how I would designate which sub-grid (or box, block etc) a specific cell belongs to. My initial impression was to have if statements in the for loops, such as if row < 2 (rows start at 0) & col < 2 then we're in the 1st block, but that seems to get messy. Would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: if (i,j) are the coordinates of the cell, then (i/3,j/3) are the coordinates of the block.

Comment: For a sodoku solver, you may want to think a little about speed, and use precalculated lookup tables. An 81-item array to look up which block a cell is in will be fast and simple. Not an answer because you still need to generate that array, though you could just fill it in manually as a static data block if you're patient enough.

Comment: @Steve314 When considering speed, please prefer simple calculations over lookup. A full memory read is expensive. Only when the answer happens to be in the L1 cache, looking it up might not be slower (but it's still eating valuable L1 cache space).

Comment: @Sjoerd - an 81-byte table isn't exactly huge, and given that the whole algorithm is short, should be in the L1 cache anyway for all but the first call. But you're probably right about the simple calculation being smaller, on reflection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could calculate a block number from row and column like this:

```
int block = (row/3)*3 + (col/3);
```

This numbers the blocks like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a lookup table with 81 entrys. Each entry refers to a cell in the 9x9 grid and gives you the information you need (which box, which column, which row, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I use this myself (but then in python, assuming x and y go from 0 to 9 exclusive):

```
int bx, by;
for (bx = (x/3)*3; bx < (x/3)*3 + 3; bx++) {
    for (by = (y/3)*3; by < (y/3)*3 + 3; by++) {
        // bx and by will now loop over each number in the block which also contains x, y
    }
}
```