# Creating 9 subarrays from a 9x9 2d array java

Tags: java, sudoku, arrays

Hello I need help creating 9 sub arrays of 3x3 dimensions from a 9x9 array.  I've seen that stackOverflow had a similar question already asked but unfortunately it was in c++. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to create a a sub array.

Edit: had aa similar changed to had a similar

```
public static void Validate(final int[][] sudokuBoard)
{
    int width = sudokuBoard[0].length;
    int height = sudokuBoard.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)

        if(!IsValidRow(sudokuBoard, i, width))
        {
            System.out.print("(Row)" + i + "  Error Detected \n");
          //Do something - The row has repetitions
        }
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        if(!IsValidColumn(sudokuBoard, j, height))
        {
            System.out.print(" (Column)" + j + "  Error Detected \n");
          //Do something - The columns has repetitions
        }
  // for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    //  if(!isBlock1Valid(sudokuBoard,width, height)){
        //  System.out.print("hi");
        //}

}

static boolean isBlock1Valid(int[][] sudokuBoard, int referenceRow, int referenceColumn)
{
    block1
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

            if ( seen[sudokuBoard[referenceColumn+i][referenceRow+j]]) return false;


    else ( seen[sudokuBoard[referenceColumn+i][referenceRow+j]]) = true;
    }
    }
return true;
}
```

this is my validate class that calls the boolean expression that i have implemented. I'm unsure the parameters to send the boolean in Validate. and thought about rearranging it so that i send Blocks of 3x3 dimensions instead.

and the c++ link
[Dividing a 9x9 2d array into 9 sub-grids (like in sudoku)? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718213/dividing-a-9x9-2d-array-into-9-sub-grids-like-in-sudoku-c)

Comment: can you share the link of C++ question?

Comment: updated the question with my current code. and link to c++ questions

Comment: I wonder do you realize that the array represented in memory as continuous block, so it is all about the indexes.

Comment: no i don't, I do however somewhat get the concept of just thinking about the indexes.

Comment: you do not need to split the board to 9 pieces, you need to write a validator method that takes in account on which block you are working now (you have 9 blocks lets name them A-I) so pass the validate method the reference to the entire 9X9 board and the name of the block to validate validate(int[9][9] board, SOME_CUSTOM_ENUM)... then inside do the index arithmetics and logic

Comment: @VOr take a look at my code for understanding the conversion of indexes from 2D to 1D and from 1D to 3D arrays.

Comment: so my boolean isBlock1Valid has to do some sort of arithmetics that declare which block it is in? but calling the boolean from Validate is where i get stumped, I'm unsure of what parameters to send it. I thought it would be simple the array sudokuBoard, int i, and int j

Comment: @Downvoter : Do always care to interpret, what is wrong and where, atleast give chance to people to improve by sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code snippet, it can show you different indices inside a given block, as obtained by using int `block = (((row / 3) * 3) + (column / 3));`

```
import java.util.*;

public class TwoDArray
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
        int[][] array = {    
                             {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},       
                             {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},                                                                                       
                             {18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26},
                             {27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35},
                             {36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44},
                             {45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53},
                             {54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62},
                             {63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71},
                             {72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80}
                            };  

        displayMatrix(array);
        displayEachBlock(array);        
    }

    private static void displayMatrix(int[][] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3 || i == 6)
                System.out.println("------------------------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.format("%-3s", array[i][j]);
                if (j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8)
                    System.out.print(" | ");
            }           
            System.out.println();   
        }      
        System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    }

    private static void displayEachBlock(int[][] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3)
        {           
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j += 3)
            {
                /*
                 * Here we are finding which block we are standing at.
                 */
                int block = (((i / 3) * 3) + (j / 3));
                System.out.println("Block : " + block);
                int[][] newArray = new int[3][3];
                int newRow = 0;
                for (int k = i; k < (i + 3); k++)
                {
                    int newColumn = 0;
                    for (int l = j; l < (j + 3); l++)
                    {
                        // This is where you are getting your array inside the given block.
                        newArray[newRow][newColumn] = array[k][l];
                        System.out.format("[%-1s][%-1s] : %-3s ", newRow, newColumn, newArray[newRow][newColumn++]);
                    }
                    newRow++;
                    System.out.println();
                }
                // Here you can send your newArray for VALIDATION, thingy.
                // So that we can move on to the next Block for further processing.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output of this code snippet :

```
0  1  2   | 3  4  5   | 6  7  8   |
9  10 11  | 12 13 14  | 15 16 17  |
18 19 20  | 21 22 23  | 24 25 26  |
------------------------------------
27 28 29  | 30 31 32  | 33 34 35  |
36 37 38  | 39 40 41  | 42 43 44  |
45 46 47  | 48 49 50  | 51 52 53  |
------------------------------------
54 55 56  | 57 58 59  | 60 61 62  |
63 64 65  | 66 67 68  | 69 70 71  |
72 73 74  | 75 76 77  | 78 79 80  |
------------------------------------
Block : 0
[0][0] : 0   [0][1] : 1   [0][2] : 2
[1][0] : 9   [1][1] : 10  [1][2] : 11
[2][0] : 18  [2][1] : 19  [2][2] : 20
Block : 1
[0][0] : 3   [0][1] : 4   [0][2] : 5
[1][0] : 12  [1][1] : 13  [1][2] : 14
[2][0] : 21  [2][1] : 22  [2][2] : 23
Block : 2
[0][0] : 6   [0][1] : 7   [0][2] : 8
[1][0] : 15  [1][1] : 16  [1][2] : 17
[2][0] : 24  [2][1] : 25  [2][2] : 26
Block : 3
[0][0] : 27  [0][1] : 28  [0][2] : 29
[1][0] : 36  [1][1] : 37  [1][2] : 38
[2][0] : 45  [2][1] : 46  [2][2] : 47
Block : 4
[0][0] : 30  [0][1] : 31  [0][2] : 32
[1][0] : 39  [1][1] : 40  [1][2] : 41
[2][0] : 48  [2][1] : 49  [2][2] : 50
Block : 5
[0][0] : 33  [0][1] : 34  [0][2] : 35
[1][0] : 42  [1][1] : 43  [1][2] : 44
[2][0] : 51  [2][1] : 52  [2][2] : 53
Block : 6
[0][0] : 54  [0][1] : 55  [0][2] : 56
[1][0] : 63  [1][1] : 64  [1][2] : 65
[2][0] : 72  [2][1] : 73  [2][2] : 74
Block : 7
[0][0] : 57  [0][1] : 58  [0][2] : 59
[1][0] : 66  [1][1] : 67  [1][2] : 68
[2][0] : 75  [2][1] : 76  [2][2] : 77
Block : 8
[0][0] : 60  [0][1] : 61  [0][2] : 62
[1][0] : 69  [1][1] : 70  [1][2] : 71
[2][0] : 78  [2][1] : 79  [2][2] : 80
```

Comment: This looks really impressive. My follow up question is where do I put in my array information to fill the new blocks?

Comment: Aren't you getting the values for these blocks from your 9X9 matrix that  you had in the start? These are not new blocks rather blocks from your original 9X9 matrix. I just never added values to array variable of the 9X9 matrix, so it's empty. Hence I showed you the indices only in this program.

Comment: @VOr : Here try this new program I just made, how to get block values :-) Hope this will put more light

Comment: It really does. Thank you so much. All your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @VOr : Here you are filling new values to the newly created array in this which represent each block. Pass this to your validation method.

Comment: @VOr : Your Welcome. Glad to be of any help to you on this. Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: It worked almost flawlessly. I just ran into ArrayIndexOutOfBound:9. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a 9x9 2D array of integers. Your aim is dividing it into 9 3x3 2D array of integers. Take a look at `check()` method which controls a 3x3 array for duplicate digits.
If it finds duplicate digits, it returns false;

Scrutinize and test my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] input = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                         {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
                         {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
                         {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
                         {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                         {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6},
                         {7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7},
                         {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8},
                         {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}};

        int[][][] output = get3DVersion(input);

        for(int i=1; i<=output.length; i++)
            System.out.println("Validity of subArray #"+i+" : " +check(output[i-1]));
    }

    public static boolean check(int[][] array)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> soFar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
             for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
             {
                 if(soFar.contains(array[j][k]))
                     return false;
                 else
                     soFar.add(array[j][k]);
             }
         return true;
    }

    public static int[][][] get3DVersion(int[][] input)
    {
        int[][][] output = new int[9][3][3];

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                for(int k=0; k<3; k++)
                    output[i][j][k] = input[i][j*3+k];

        output[8][2][2] = input[8][8];

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why a 3d array help me in my case. Thank you for the suggestion. Very much appreciated

Comment: You mention about 9 of 3x3 arrays. This means a 3D array. Am i wrong?

Comment: I might have worded it incorrectly. I was referring to 9 [3][3] arrays.

Comment: Ok with these code you are already getting 9 [3][3] arrays which is "output" in get3DVersion() method. You can get and use them separately. Give it a try. It is simple. For example output[0] refers to your first 3X3 array.

Comment: it's just im unsure how i would create a boolean to check all the integers of a 3d array to make sure 1-9 only appear once.

Comment: Your question title is "Creating 9 subarrays from a 9x9 2d array java" and my coding is doing what you ask in your question. I say that get3DVersion() returns you 9 arrays each one is 3x3 array, then you can check them one by one with your condition. If this is not you want format your question please.

Comment: Well yes the question is asking for the creating of 3x3 arrays from a 9x9 but the next step for me and the code is to check the integers within the new blocks to ensure that no integer appears more than once.

Comment: And I'm assuming you were the one that voted down on my question.