# How can I loop through a Sudoku board?

Tags: java, sudoku

For example, say we have a Sudoku board like this:

```
0 0 6 5 8 9 7 4 3
0 5 0 0 0 0 0 6 0
7 0 9 0 6 0 1 0 0
0 3 0 0 0 2 0 8 7
0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0
8 9 0 6 0 0 0 5 0
0 0 2 0 5 0 3 0 6
0 7 0 0 0 0 0 9 0
3 1 8 4 9 6 5 0 0
```

I want to store it into one array such that the first 9 elements of the array are the first sub block, i.e. the values `{0 0 6 0 5 0 7 0 9}` and followed by `{5 8 9 0 0 0 0 6 0}`.

I've tried finding a solution but I always get an array index out of bounds error and it is too brute force. Something similar to this:

```
          while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if(ctr == 27) {
                c.addSubBlock(sb1);
                c.addSubBlock(sb2);
                c.addSubBlock(sb3);
                sb1 = new SubBlock();
                sb2 = new SubBlock();
                sb3 = new SubBlock();
                ctr = 0;
            }
            sb1.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb1.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb1.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb2.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb2.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb2.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb3.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb3.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            sb3.addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
            ctr+=9;
        }
```

Please give me some tips. Code snippets would also be a great help.

EDIT: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718213/dividing-a-9x9-2d-array-into-9-sub-grids-like-in-sudoku-c) somehow helped me figured it out. And yes, this is part of the Sudoku where I'm trying to encode the board into an array.

What I did was to transform first the input String into a 2d array (9x9) and use `int block = (row/3)*3 + (col/3);` to compute exactly which sub block each element belongs.

Comment: Well, without knowing what `c` or `SubBlock` are/do, pretty hard to tell where that exception is coming from. There are no visible array manipulations in the code you posted.

Comment: I think the exception I'm getting has nothing to do with `c` or `SubBlock`. I'm also not very interested of solving the exception. Rather on how to form the array of sub blocks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a 3x3 array of sub blocks
2. Use 2 counters (x & y) for tracking the position in the full board of each element read
3. Add the values at (x,y) into sub block (x/3,y/3)

Something like this:

```
SubBlock board[][] = new SubBlock[3][3];
int x, y;
for ( y=0; y<9; y++ )
  for ( x=0; x<9; x++ )
    board[y/3][x/3].addElement(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
```

board[0][0] will be the top-left SubBlock, board[2][2] the bottom-right one.

Comment: can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Store everything in a two dimension array. E.g.

```
int[] board = {
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}};

//looping
public static void Main(string[] args){
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    System.out.println("SubBlock number"+i);
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
      System.out.println(board[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not group the numbers into sub blocks.

Comment: I am not familiar with a sub block class. I showed you an easy way to group your board squares and loop through them. It should definetely do the trick, unless you have some special methods in sub block class. In that case you could just edit those methods a little to work with a particular part of the two dimensional array

Comment: And yes, it does group numbers into sub blocks. See where I declared the board. Every row represents a sub block

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are reading input left to right, top to bottom, try a set of 4 nested loops like this:

```
int board[] = new int[81];
for (int outY = 0; outY < 3; outY++)
{
   for (int outX = 0; outX < 3; outX++)
   {
      for (int inY = 0; inY < 3; inY++)
      {

         for (int inX = 0; inX < 3; inX++)
         {
             board[27*outY + 9*outX + 3 * inY + inX] = //parse an int from your input here
         }
      }        
   }    
}
```

Comment: 4 nested loops... wow, I dont get the idea behind this one. Looking at the OP's code snippet, the input is rowbased. So if really using a 1 dimensional array, it can be initalized in a simple for loop with i=0; i<81; Getting a value would result in something like: 'get second element in third row', which has to be flattened out for the 1 dimensional array.

Comment: The OP wants it transformed so that elements within a sub-block are together in the array.  Reading it in as in would split each sub-block across 3 different locations within the array.

"I want to store it into one array such that the first 9 elements of the array are the first sub block, i.e. the values {0 0 6 0 5 0 7 0 9} and followed by {5 8 9 0 0 0 0 6 0}."

Comment: I see your point now, one row represents a subblock. I wonder why the OP needs this one... :) For sudoku solving, several checks are needed anyway: vertical row, horizontal row and the subblock.

Comment: He mentioned a "chromosome encoding for the genetic algorithm" in another comment.  This isn't the way I would go about solving Sudoku, but I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt on that and answering what he asked.

Comment: @jlewis42 it's a school project and one of the requirements is to use a ga. I'm adapting a research method and that's what they did, used sub blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if we knew why you are trying to loop through the board.

If you want to check if you can enter a number, I recommend you use maps for each of the 3x3 squares.
Then check if the item is in the map already or not. For the rows and columns, you can either loop over the 2D array and check each element, or -again- use a map for each column and a map for each row.

Comment: I'm trying to loop through the board because I'm forming a chromosome encoding for the genetic algorithm. I would like to build my chromosome in such a way that the first 9 elements of the array is the first sub block, and so on.

Comment: @braindead please remove Sudoku form the title since the question has nothing to do with the game. Just call it a board/2D_array

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you want an answer for a single-dimension array or if you're willing to make it a two-dimensional array (as you mention each nine element set with curly braces), but if two-dimensional is OK...

The [OP in this Code Review posting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37430/sudoku-solver-in-c) used a 'fancy' way of sifting through the subgrids by using the math `(i % 3) + rowStart` inside one of the square brackets and `(i / 3) + colStart` inside the other. One commenter noted this modulo method to be a bit obscure, and I'm prone to agree, but for how clean it is and the fact that it works, I think it's a solid solution. So, paired with the iteration of the for loop, we can sift through each 'subgrid' cell, as well as each element of row + col.

```
for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
    if (puzzle[row][i] == num) return 0;
    if (puzzle[i][col] == num) return 0;
    if (puzzle[rowStart + (i%3)][colStart + (i/3)] == num) return 0;
}
```

If we find a number in one of the cells that matches, it's a duplicate, and we exit the function as 'false', or, 0.

**EDIT:**

Now that I think of it, you could use this same trick for a single-dimension array by using `i % 9` instead of 3. You could then determine which 'row' we're on by doing `i / 9` and trusting that, since we're dealing with type `int`s, we'll truncate the unnecessary decimals.

This does verify that this trick is a bit prone towards N-1 indexed data, as someone would assume 'go to the 81st element' would mean go to the 9th column of the 9th row, but using 81 % 9 would yield 0, and 81 / 9 would yield 9, so we'd go to the 0th place at row 9.