# How to get a region for a cell in Sudoku 2D array?

Tags: c++, sudoku

I made a board of 9 rows and 9 columns for making a sudoku. 
I am trying to get the rows and columns and the region for any cell passed to my method - Getpossiblevalues().

I have made the array values which reads from a text file and adds to each cell. I have not shown that code here though. At the moment i can only do it by checking row number each time and column number such as check if row = 0, row = 1 etc..,

```
int main(){
board[9][9]; //creates a 9*9 matrix or a 2d array.


for(int i=0; i<9; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cout << board[i][j]  << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 getPossiblevalues(0,0);




int getPossiblevalues(int row, int col) {

set<int> d;
set<int> e;


//Get Rows
for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    d.insert(board[row][j]);
}

//Get Columns
for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) {

    d.insert(board[k][col]);
}

//Get Region
if((row == 0)|| (row ==1)||(row ==2) && ((col == 1)|| (col ==2) ||(col ==3)){

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {

            d.insert(board[i][j]);
        }

    }
}




    for (auto i : d){

    cout <<i<<" ";
}
```

}

Comment: You should at least *give it a try* before asking that here.

Comment: @roeland check edit. i can get the region but i am checking row number each time. just seeing if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718213/dividing-a-9x9-2d-array-into-9-sub-grids-like-in-sudoku-c?rq=1 for a solution