# How to iterate over Sudoku sub-grid using c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do an online Sudoku c++ test problem.

I need to determine if a 9x9 Sudoku board is valid. Only the filled cells need to be validated according to the following rules (some cells have '.' to indicate they not filled in):

1. Each row must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
2. Each column must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
3. Each of the 9 3x3 sub-boxes of the grid must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.

For my solution, I'm looping through each row, column, and sub-box grid. Adding those numbers to a map. And checking if that map has any duplicates.

I'm pretty sure I have criteria `1` and `2` solved, but I was having trouble imagining how to loop through sub-box 3x3 grid. So I adapted [some code found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4718285/1526396), which to be honest I still can't fully wrap my head around. I think that part might be causing the problem.

How do I solve criteria 3?

Example input, a correct answer should return False but my code returns True:

```
[
[".",".","4",".",".",".","6","3","."],
[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
["5",".",".",".",".",".",".","9","."],
[".",".",".","5","6",".",".",".","."],
["4",".","3",".",".",".",".",".","1"],
[".",".",".","7",".",".",".",".","."],
[".",".",".","5",".",".",".",".","."],
[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."]
]
```

My (broken) solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValidSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {

        //Iterate over each row
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            //Add row numbers to map
            map<char, int> row_nums {};
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if (board[x][i] != '.') {
                    row_nums[board[x][i]]++;
                }
            }
            //Return false if duplicates found in row map
            for (auto it = row_nums.begin(); it != row_nums.end(); ++it) {
                if (it->second > 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Iterate over columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            //Add column numbers to map
            map<char, int> col_nums {};
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                if (board[i][y] != '.') {
                    col_nums[board[i][y]]++;
                }
            }
            //Return false if duplicates found in column map
            for (auto it = col_nums.begin(); it != col_nums.end(); it++) {
                if (it->second > 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Iterate over the 3x3 sub-boxes and add numbers to a map
        //I think this is where I am stuck
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                map<char, int> box_nums {};
                for (int bx = (x/3)*3; bx < (x/3)*3 + 3; bx++) {
                    for (int by = (y/3)*3; by < (y/3)*3 + 3; by++) {
                        if (board[bx][by] != '.') {
                            box_nums[board[bx][by]]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Return false if duplicates found in column map
                for (auto it = box_nums.begin(); it != box_nums.end(); it++) {
                    if (it->second > 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }            
        }

        //Else return true
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You are not asking a question. Please read [ask]. Also, if you have problems with some code, extract a [mcve] first.

Comment: Added an explicit question in case it wasn't clear enough. All code was necessary to see my solution, and answers have been based on what I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you shared is valid Sudoku w.r.t sub-boxes. There is a problem in column 4 where there are two `5`. The logic in column check has to be changed to iterate over each row keeping the column fixed.

```
 //Iterate over columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            //Add column numbers to map
            map<char, int> col_nums {};
            for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                if (board[y][i] != '.') {
                    col_nums[board[y][i]]++;
                }
            }
            //Return false if duplicates found in column map
            for (auto it = col_nums.begin(); it != col_nums.end(); it++) {
                if (it->second > 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

This should fix your issue.

Not sure about your subbox issue, but here is another way of getting subboxes without doing `(bx/3)*3` etc

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x+=3) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y+=3) {
        map<char, int> box_nums{};
        for (int bx = x; bx < x + 3; bx++) {
            for (int by = y; by < y + 3; by++) {
                if (board[bx][by] != '.') {
                    box_nums[board[bx][by]]++;
                }
            }
        }
        //Return false if duplicates found in column map
        for (auto it = box_nums.begin(); it != box_nums.end(); it++) {
            if (it->second > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has this helped me a lot. But now I'm seeing a `line 3:  4863 Segmentation fault (core dumped) ${command}` error. I pasted my code to an online compiler and it works fine: http://www.cpp.sh/3v6l. Any idea what's wrong? Googling the error message and apparently it means I am pointing to an area of memory outside of what was allocated. I cannot figure out how that's happening though.

Comment: In the link, the condition should be `by < y + 3;` It's showing as `by < by + 3` which would never break. Changing it should fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do not need a `std::map` and use the second loop to validate if any has count bigger than 1, just use `std::set` and if insert operation returns false that means duplicate found. Second you can just have 3 arrays of `std::set` and iterate over all rows and columns at once and just find proper `std::set` for each item:

```
const size_t size = 9;
using cset = std::set<char>;
using sets = std::array<cset,size>;

sets columns, rows, squares;

for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    for( size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j ) {
        char n = board[i][j];
        if( not checkSet( columns[i], n ) ) return false;
        if( not checkSet( rows[j], n ) ) return false;
        if( not checkSet( squares[i/3 + j/3*3], n ) ) return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

where `checkSet()` can be as simple as this:

```
bool checkSet( cset &s, char n )
{
     return s.insert( n ).second;
}
```

Note: if you care about efficiency you should use `std::array<bool,size>` instead of `std::set`, convert your chars to numbers 0-8 and use it as index in that array.

Comment: I think I'm following this all the way until `squares[i%3 + (j%3) * 3]`. Would you mind explaining how this part works? I'm having trouble imagining how this works on a 2D plane.

Comment: @TinyTiger  actually I made a mistake, it should be `i/3 + j/3*3` you can see it here https://ideone.com/zlzWhZ